# Incorrect use of <label for=FORM_ELEMENT> - How to fix?

Tags: html, section508

I am creating a dropdown on my page which cascades information from one column to another. Everything works fine however, the browser throws the following error. How do I fix this? Any help appreciated.

> Incorrect use of 
> The label's for attribute doesn't match any element id. This might prevent the browser from correctly autofilling the form and accessibility tools from working correctly.
> To fix this issue, make sure the label's for attribute references the correct id of a form field.

Please see my code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    searching: true,
    columnDefs: [
            {
                target: 6,
                visible: false,
                searchable: true,
            }
      ],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                orientation: 'landscape',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                     }
              },           
            {
                extend: 'print',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
               },
        //  'colvis'
        ],
  });

  buildSelect(table);
 
  table.on('draw', function() {
    buildSelect(table);
  });
  $('#test').on('click', function() {
    table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
  });
});

function buildSelect(table) {
  var counter = 0;
  table.columns([0, 1, 2]).every(function() {
    var column = table.column(this, {
      search: 'applied'
    });
    counter++;
    var select = $('<select><option value="">select me</option></select>')
      .appendTo($('#dropdown' + counter).empty())
      .on('change', function() {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val()
        );

        column
          .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });

    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
      select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
    });

    // The rebuild will clear the exisiting select, so it needs to be repopulated
    var currSearch = column.search();
    if (currSearch) {
      // ** MY CHANGE **
      // Use RegEx to find the selected value from the unique values of the column.
      // This will use the Regular Expression returned from column.search to find the first matching item in column.data().unique
      select.val(column.data().unique().toArray().find((e) => e.match(new RegExp(currSearch))));
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

    
    
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
<div class="searchbox">
<p>Name: 
  
  <span id="dropdown1">
  </span>
</p>

<p>Postion: <span id="dropdown2">
  </span>
</p>

<p>Office: <span id="dropdown3">
</span>
</p>
  <button type="button" id="test">Clear Filters</button>
</div>
  <table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;"><thead>
<tr>

<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
  <th>&#160;</th>
</tr>


          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Hidden Column</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
Test1</td>


            <td>test2</td>
            <td>test3</td>
            <td>test4</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
            <td>Sys Architect</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett -2</td>
            <td>Director: fgghghjhjhjhkjkj</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
            <td>Director:</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton.1 -2</td>
            <td>Technical Authorjkjkjk fdfd h gjjjhjhk</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
            <td>Tech author</td>
          </tr>
          
            
          </tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: The browser is only telling you that you are making inconsistent use of HTML language syntax. As long as your writing HTML code does not respect its usage, it will continue to send you this message.

Comment: also : `<div>` elements doesn't have a `select="select"` attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes

Comment: You should probably skim the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for any element you're using here. You need some foundational knowledge of HTML. Pay particular attention to allowed attributes and permitted content.

Answer (score 8):

`<label>`s label **form controls** like `<input>`, or `<select>`.

They can't be used to label arbitrary elements, including `<span>`.

Replace the `<label>` (and maybe also the `<span>`) elements with something that has more appropriate semantics.

Maybe you are looking for a [description list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl). Maybe the drop down elements contain form controls, in which case you might be looking for [`<legend>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend) and [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset). Use `<div>`/`<span>` if no element has appropriate semantics.

Comment: That and the IDs don't match.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this as I am still learbing HTML. Can you please update my code example? Thanks.

Comment: @newuser — You see how I repeatedly used the word "Maybe" in the final paragraph of my answer? There isn't enough information in your data for me to confidently determine the correct semantics for the data you are marking up. You need to learn what the elements in HTML mean (you can focus on the ones I linked to above) and select the ones which match your data.

Comment: This is a great question because of custom form controls in frameworks like Angular. You can create a formcontrol out of anything.  So how do we navigate that?

Comment: @BenRacicot — If you have a new question then you can [ask one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) making sure to include a [mcve] (I would expect that when you created a form control in Angular you would be generating an `<input>` or other standard HTML form control in the DOM)) and (if relevant) link to this answer.